# Incrementing number in string with leading zeros

Tags: php

I have the following string "S_000308".

What would be the best way to increment the number by one? eg: "S_000309" "S_000310", .....

I tried various methods but the problem seems to be with the leading zero's which make it hard.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which method did you use that was closest?

Comment: Also, check out https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php

Answer (score 2):

You're overcomplicating it. :) Perl had this magic, and many languages, including PHP, inherited it:

```
$x = "S_000308";
$x++;
echo $x;
// => S_000309
```

EDIT: Took a bit of searching for the right bit in the docs, but [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php) there's an explanation, followed by some examples:

> PHP follows Perl's convention when dealing with arithmetic operations on character variables and not C's. For example, in PHP and Perl `$a = 'Z'; $a++;` turns `$a` into `'AA'`, while in C `a = 'Z'; a++;` turns `a` into `'['` (ASCII value of `'Z'` is 90, ASCII value of `'['` is 91). Note that character variables can be incremented but not decremented and even so only plain ASCII alphabets and digits (`a-z`, `A-Z` and `0-9`) are supported. Incrementing/decrementing other character variables has no effect, the original string is unchanged.

Comment: I'm baffled by the simplicity

Comment: It's not obvious if you don't know about it. As I said, it's magic. You'd be even more baffled by what would happen if `$x` were to be e.g. `AA999`. :D

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the number with :

```
$number = intval(substr($string, 2));
```

And then formate the number with :

```
$string = "S_" . str_pad($number, 6, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

And in between you can do all the operation you want with `$number`, for example `$number++;` for incrementation.

Answer (score 0):

PHP can recognize the trailing numbers in strings and perform well for operator overloading.

```
$strNum = "Next year is 2019";

$strNum++;   // Next year is 2020
```

Comment: This is incorrect. `$strNum + 1` does _not_ do this. It is only `++` that is magical, not all maths. Also, `++` automatically assigns its value, and `$strNum = $strNum++` actually increments `$strNum` and then _rolls it back to its original value_ (so the result is actually `"Next year is 2019"`!). Be careful about combining increment/decrement operators with assignment!